# No element found message for findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-index='1']

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am using the following code to make a test for the below scenario

- Create Selenium Web browser tests using Java language for amazon.com with the following details:
- Search Nikon and sort results from highest price to slowest.
- Select the second product and click it for details.

```
public void test() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/dimuthugunarathna/browserdrivers/chromedriver 3");
        ChromeDriver driver  = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://amazon.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("Nikon");
        
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#nav-search-submit-button")).click();
        
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#a-autoid-0-announce[data-action='a-dropdown-button']")).click();
        
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[aria-labelledby='s-result-sort-select_2']")).click();

        WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 's-main-slot')]"));
        System.out.println(parent.getAttribute("class"));
        
        WebElement child = parent.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-index='1']"));
    
        System.out.println(child.getAttribute("class"));
        
        WebElement childLink =child.findElement(By.cssSelector(".a-link-normal"));
        childLink.click();
```

WebElement child = parent.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-index='1']")); always cause no element found error. Could someone help me here?[image]

Comment: Try adding .// to that xpath also print out the parents innerhtml to see if that element has that xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever you try to find element that is child of a parent you should use '.' for xpath to indicate that the current node is the indicate:

eg:

```
WebElement child = parent.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@data-index='1']"));
```

This will search for

```
//div[contains(@class, 's-main-slot')]//div[@data-index='1']
```

if you don't add '.' then the search will be from the root node. The equalent xpath will be

```
//div[@data-index='1']
```

### But this limitation is applicable only for xpath

```
WebElement child = parent.findElement(By.class("new"));
```

**will be same as :**

```
//div[contains(@class, 's-main-slot')]//*[@class='new']
```